# Were ALL plants and animals existing right now humans in a previous birth?

Tags: karma, rebirth

Some plants and animals were humans in previous lives, but were ALL of them like that? Or is it only SOME of them?

Have any theologians, throughout the history of Hinduism, asked and answered this question?

Comment: Have wondered this too. When I first went toward vegan environmentalist living, I remember hearing Hindu shastras quotation that to cut down tree is huge huge paap, should never do it. Is not right, live in harmony w/ nature. So horrid watching people cut down forests to build golf courses & shopping centers ?? No thx ?? Anyway hopefully some knowledgeable types replies here w/ answers whether all plants/trees were persons in pichle janm. I like to know too. Saw a wonderful artwork w/ Krishn walking in meadow w/ the trees, grass, flowers leaning toward him w/ such devotion. Made me cry